# GetModuleName returns extraneous characters

Tags: delphi

I am using the above function within a DLL to obtain its full path. The DLL is an ISAPI dll and is located at `"c:\inetpub\dlls"`. The `GetModuleName` function returns `"\\?\c:inetpb\dlls\DLL.exe"`.

I don't understand why the function returns the extraneous characters at the start. It is not a huge issue as I can simply strip the first three characters, unless of course the function does not always return these same characters on different servers, in which case there is a problem.

Can anyone explain why it does this and whether it will do so consistently on all servers?

I have searched Google and there is as far as I can see nothing relating to this.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't `\\?\`? Maybe you could search for [UNC paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file)?

Comment: @Andreas It was an issue with the formatting

Comment: That is right it should have been '\\?' and the link you have provided seems to be the answer, although I don't quite understand why this prefix is appended in my example.

Comment: Why do you feel that you need to remove the prefix?

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you are using the function [GetModuleFileName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamea) (that's what a search for `GetModuleName` returns).

The documentation for `GetModuleFileName` states that ... *The string returned will use the same format that was specified when the module was loaded. Therefore, the path can be a long or short file name, and can use the prefix "\?"*.

I guess the save route is to always check for the prefix unless you are absolutely certain that the returned path consistently either is prefixed or not depending on the process that loaded the DLL.

Comment: `GetModuleName` is a Delphi wrapper for `GetModuleFileName`. I get the DLL path so I can open an ini file from the same location. I am having problems with the DLL (which is tricky to debug) and I thought the problem stemmed from its inability to load the ini file. However, it may be that there are other reasons and that the prefix is not causing a problem.